# Android Internationalization not working for some Android devices

Tags: java, android, android-resources

I have an android app that targets the SDK Version 25 and the min SDK 17. This is app is supposed to be in 4 languages : **French**, **Swahili**, **English** and **Kirundi**.

But for some android devices, all four languages work properly but for some others, all other languages work except **Kirundi** when the user switches to it.

Here is my code:

```java
public class LanguageSwitcher extends AppCompatActivity {

    //Variables declaration
    private TextView bdi,en,fr,sw;

    private Resources res;
    private DisplayMetrics dm;
    android.content.res.Configuration conf;


    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_language_switcher);


        bdi = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.bdi); //Kirundi textview
        fr  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.fr); //francais textview
        en  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.en); //english textview
        sw  = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.sw); //swahili textview


        res = getResources();
        dm  = res.getDisplayMetrics();
        conf= res.getConfiguration();


        //getting the sharedPreferences 
        SharedPreferences sharedPreferences=getSharedPreferences("profile", Context.MODE_PRIVATE);

        String lang = sharedPreferences.getString("lang","");

        final SharedPreferences.Editor editor = sharedPreferences.edit();

        bdi.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                conf.locale = new Locale("rn"); // API 17+ only.
                editor.putString("lang","rn");
                editor.apply();
                res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Acceuil.class));
            }
        });
        fr.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                conf.locale = new Locale("fr"); // API 17+ only.
                editor.putString("lang","fr");
                editor.apply();
                res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Acceuil.class));
            }
        });
        sw.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                conf.locale = new Locale("sw"); // API 17+ only.
                editor.putString("lang","sw");
                editor.apply();
                res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Acceuil.class));
            }
        });
        en.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                conf.locale = new Locale("en"); // API 17+ only.
                editor.putString("lang","en");
                editor.apply();
                res.updateConfiguration(conf, dm);
                startActivity(new Intent(getApplicationContext(),Acceuil.class));
            }
        });
    }
}
```

I don't know where I am wrong with my code. I need your help

Comment: Do those "some devices" have anything in common, such as OEM, API, etc?

Comment: I tried with Nexus API 24 KIRUNDI worked, SAMSUNG API 24 Kirundi didn't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I made some researches and found that unlike other languages, Kirundi resources should be under `res/values-rn-rBI` folder instead of `res/values-rn` folder. `rn` as **ISO 639-1** language code like for any other language in Android and `BI` the  **ISO 3166-1 Alpha-2 Code** for the country (Burundi) and that worked.

Answer (score 1):

We can use custom fonts. They can either be [Downloadable Fonts](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/downloadable-fonts) or we can give [Fonts in XML](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml)

You can use [this link](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/look-and-feel/fonts-in-xml) for more info on how to integrate fonts in XML in the Android App.

Basically, we can provide the `ttf` or `otf` file in the app itself so that we can use the fonts in our app, instead of depending on the OEM font.

[image]

Check the links for the step by step guide on the Android Developer website.

Comment: Sir, any language can only be displayed if you have the respective font files. Please correct me if I am wrong.

Comment: Maybe I didn't explain correctly it's not about displaying but translating

Comment: For example: Salut (French) -- Hi (English)-- Jambo (Swahili) -- Mwaramutse (Kirundi)

Answer (score 0):

set your language before onCreate()
 or super.onCreate()

Comment: I set the language when the user picks it and then I open the activity `Acceuil`

Comment: I knew that,I mean set it again after user choosing a language when activity recreating.